# python 2D array. different initiation got same result, but different manipulation result

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

what's the main difference between these two ways of 2d array initiation

```
m1 = [[0]*5]*5
m2 = [[0 for x in range(5)]for y in range(5)]
```

this code gives me the exact 2d Array I want as I printed the result

```
print('m1 == m2 ?',m1 == m2)
print('m1',m1)
print('m2',m2)
```

result from console:

```
m1 == m2 ? True
m1 [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
m2 [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

However, when I tried to modify its values as `m[i][0]= i and m[0][j] = j`, I got two totally different results as following code

```
for i in range(5):
    m1[i][0] = i
    m2[i][0] = i

for j in range(5):
    m1[0][j] = j
    m2[0][j] = j

print('m1 == m2 ?',m1 == m2)
print('m1 after',m1)
print('m2 after',m2)
```

and the result:

```
m1 == m2 ? False
m1 after [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
m2 after [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

obviously, m2 is the one I need. is it wrong to declare a 2d array using m1's method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in `[[0]*5]*5` the outermost list is filled with the same list in all its 5 positions.

You should do:

```
[[0]*5 for y in range(5)]
```

Comment: that makes sense. does it mean the outer lists are just 4 references of the first list?